# Iterar setState en Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo el siguiente problema, he creado una API REST y me he traido los datos al Front con React, el caso es que como se ve en el codigo he iterado los `options` y lo que quiero es usar uno o multiples useState para cambiar el valor de una imagen, (cada option contiene como se puede ver un id, title e image)

```
options.map( ({_id, title, selectId, image}) => (
                    (data._id === selectId) ?
                        <div key={_id} className="options">
                           <input type="radio" id={_id} name={selectId} value={title}/>
                           <label for={_id} onClick={ () => setValor1(image) }>{title}</label>
                        </div>
                    : null
                                ))
<img src={valor1}></img>
```

Quiero poner que cada option, al seleccionarlo se cambie de imagen, pero cada option esta metido en un contendor padre, llamado select, ahi podeis ver que hace una pequeña condicion a la hora de imprimir las `options`, por lo que si selecciono un `option` que esta dentro del `select 01`, me deberia de mostrar esa imagen, pero si selecciono otro `option` de otro `select`, me deberia de mostrar tambien esa imagen, las 2.

Ahora mismo me muestra la ultima que haya seleccionado, me muestra el `Option 02 del Select 01`, pero como puedo hacer para mostrar la imagen tanto esta del `Option 02 del Select 01` como para que me muestre la del `Option 01 del Select 02` ?? Cual seria la mejor forma ??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa la posición del array que trae las opciones para designar una imagen a mostrar según la opción seleccionada.

```
//La data que podría traer un fetch
const fetchedData = [
  { _id: 1, title: "Image1", image: "image_url1" },
  { _id: 2, title: "Image2", image: "image_url2" },
]
```

```
//...

const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(!loaded){
    setLoaded(true);
    setOptions(fetchedData);
    const selectedImages = fetchedData.map(item => "" ); //["", ""]
    setImages(selectedImages);
  }
},[]);

const selectImage = (imageUrl, index) => {
  const updatedImages = images.map((item, i) => i == index ? imageUrl : item );
  setImages(updatedImages);
}
```

Entonces debes agregar el index en tu map de options

```
options.map( ({_id, title, selectId, image}, index) => (
  (data._id === selectId) ?
    <div key={_id} className="options">
      <input type="radio" id={_id} name={selectId} value={title}/>
      <label for={_id} onClick={ () => selectImage(image, index) }>{title}.</label>
    </div>
    : null
  )
)
```

Y tus imágenes deberán mostrarse de esta manera

```
{images.map((img, i) => (img != "" ? <img key={i} src={img}></img> : null)}
```

Ahora lo más probable es que quieras también controlar los valores de los input. Para ese caso repite lo de la imagen y fusiona la función de selectImage() para enviarle el value del input que quieras enviar a backend.

Una opción a esto último para obtener un array de los valores seleccionados:

```
const optionsSelected = options.filter((opt, i) => images[i] != "" );
```

Comment: Lo probaré, gracias por responder